# "Opening Shows" on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a shows table and a performances table.

I am trying to find "shows about to open" by asking for "shows whose first performances occurs within the next week".

Here are the pertinent data fields:

SHOWS
id
name (varchar)
...

PERFORMANCES
id
show_id (int/fk)
date_time (datetime)
...

I am thinking the group by clause would be needed here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help would be amazing.

thanks!

Comment: Please be more specific -- can you post the DDL for your tables?

Comment: Thanks, @DavidMoles . I added the pertinent fields in my question.

Comment: @mrbenhill: *DDL* means `CREATE TABLE` statements. (*DDL* stands for "data definition language".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT shows.name, performances.date_time AS "Opening Date"
FROM shows
INNER JOIN PERFORMANCES
ON shows.id = performances.show_id
WHERE performances.date_time <= (CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 week')
AND  performances.date_time > CURRENT_DATE
```

Output from sample 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8c931/3)

**PostgreSQL 9.3.1 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Shows
    ("id" int, "name" varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO Shows
    ("id", "name")
VALUES
    (1, 'Chicago'),
    (2, 'Cats'),
    (3, 'Some other show')
;

CREATE TABLE Performances
    ("id" int, "show_id" int, "date_time" date)
;

INSERT INTO Performances
    ("id", "show_id", "date_time")
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2014-04-18'),
    (2, 2, '2014-05-18'),
    (3, 3, '2012-05-18');
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT shows.name, performances.date_time AS "Opening Date"
FROM shows
INNER JOIN PERFORMANCES
ON shows.id = performances.show_id
WHERE performances.date_time <= (CURRENT_DATE + interval '1 week')
AND  performances.date_time > CURRENT_DATE
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8c931/3/0)**:

```
|    NAME |                 OPENING DATE |
|---------|------------------------------|
| Chicago | April, 18 2014 00:00:00+0000 |
```